# when i use Select field in React Js if the value is string the select dont work , if value is integer it works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Material-ui version "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.35"
react version: "react": "^16.2.0"
Works :

```
<MenuItem value={1}>Text</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={2}>Integer</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={3}>Inline</MenuItem>
```

Dont work

```
<MenuItem value="Text">Text</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="Text">Integer</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="Text">Inline</MenuItem>
```

so how to make the value be the string and be selected .

Comment: have you tried  `value={"Text"}`

Comment: `{}` around `"strings"` literals are not necessary. the problem is that values must be unique.

Comment: @jesusiniesta i tried to use unique values on [value] property  , but it's not work.

Comment: The Simple Select demo is using integer values for its MenuItems.  Your problem is likely elsewhere.  See the demo: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep `unique value` attributes for each of your `MenuItem`, otherwise the first match will just remain selected

```
<MenuItem value="Text">Text</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="Integer">Integer</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="Inline">Inline</MenuItem>
```

Comment: i tried to use unique values on [value] property , but it's not working.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible demo of your problem